# App Created in XCode 4 running in Xcode 2.5?

Tags: xcode

I've to run some security tests on an App created by an external company for my work. The app they've created will have been done in XCode 4.x, though my work only has access to a Mac capable of running Xcode 2.5 (OS X 10.4.11).

Will the app open and run correctly in XCode 2.5 or will there be compatability issues?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an app for the Mac (Mac OS X) or for the iPhone/iPad/etc (iOS) ?

Comment: OK - you'll need to get a cheap Intel Mac then so that you can run Xcode 3.x or 4.x with the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be able to open the project.

Since the mac you have access to is limited to OS X 10.4, I asssume it is a PowerPC mac - in this case, you can't use the iOS SDK (if this is an iOS app) anyway as this is limited to Intel machines.

Comment: Yes, it's a PowerPC G5. The app will be on iOS, so thats a no go?

Comment: No go I'm afraid. I had to retire my beloved imac G5 to start developing iOS apps.

Comment: Ok, gonna have to think up a new plan for this then. Thanks for the response.